# Insert query using prepared-statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have an stored procedure like this:

```
SET @query = CONCAT('insert into tblcommodity (id , idname , count)values (',p1, p2,p3,')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

But when I want to run it, it has this error:

```
> Procedure execution failed 1136 - Column count doesn't match value
> count at row 1
```

and another thing is that when I just run the insert code it runs!

plz help me.

Comment: you prepare a statement to deallocate it just after ? and take care : CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

Comment: actually i had a long sp that this part is not executed, so i seperate this part ans test in another sp, but it doesnt run too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With all due respect, the way you do it kindof defeats the whole purpose of prepared statements. I'd use this form instead:

```
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO tblcommodity (id, idname, count) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @p1, @p2, @p3;
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
SET @query = CONCAT('insert into tblcommodity (id , idname , count)values (',',',p1,',', p2,',',p3,')');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET @query = CONCAT("insert into tblcommodity (id , idname , count) values (", p1, ", '", p2,"',",p3,")"); 
PREPARE stmt FROM @query; 
EXECUTE stmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, Your code:

```
SET @query = CONCAT('insert into tblcommodity (id , idname , count)values (',p1, p2,p3,')');
```

has an starting comma:

```
    ,p1,p2,p3
```

it means FOUR fields in the statement.
Thats why you get an  "Column count doesn't match value"